# Evict dependant collections together with parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have just realized that when an object is evicted from Hibernate cache, [dependant collections, if cached, have to be evicted ***separately***](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/08/evict-collection-from-hibernate-second.html).

For me this is a one big WTF:

- it is really easy to forget to evict a collection (e.g. when a new one is added to the object mapping);
- code for evicting dependant collections is ugly and bulky, e.g.

  `MyClass myObject = ...;`
  `getHibernateTemplate().evict(myObject);`
  `Cache cache = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCache();`
  `cache.evictCollection("my.package.MyClass.myCollection1, id);`
  `...`
  `cache.evictCollection("my.package.MyClass.myCollectionN, id);`

It is quite obvious that if parent object has changed, there is little sense to keep it's collections around as they are most likely to be derived from that parent anyway.

Am I missing something here? Is there really no way to flush an object together with all its child entities without writing all this code manually?

Comment: by 'dependent collections' you mean they're configured with a cascade like "all-delete-orphan"?

Comment: @Nathan Hughes - yes. To add to my argument list - when evicting collections, one has to pass parent id anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4910). There is a way to hook into hibernate to evict collection caches on inserting, updating or removing the collections referred entity. I have [supplied a fix for hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/580). The Fix is scheduled for Hibernate 4.3.0.Beta5 and will be activated by the property:

```
hibernate.cache.auto_evict_collection_cache=true
```

As long this fix is not realeased you can workaround to inject eviction-logic by just registering the CollectionCacheInvalidator with your SessionFactory and SessionFactoryServiceRegistry by your own.

```
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import my.own.library.BeanInformationFromClass;
import my.own.library.PropertyInformationFromClass;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.EventType;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostInsertEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PostInsertEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreDeleteEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreDeleteEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.PreUpdateEventListener;
import org.hibernate.persister.collection.CollectionPersister;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister;
import org.hibernate.persister.entity.Joinable;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;

/**
 * @author Andreas Berger (latest modification by $Author$)
 * @version $Id$
 * @created 27.08.13 - 17:49
 */
public class CollectionCacheInvalidator
        implements PostInsertEventListener, PreDeleteEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( CollectionCacheInvalidator.class );

    private Map<String, String> mappedByFieldMapping;

    public void integrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sf, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry registry) {
        EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = registry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.POST_INSERT, this );
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.PRE_DELETE, this );
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.PRE_UPDATE, this );

        mappedByFieldMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Map<String, CollectionPersister> persiters = sf.getCollectionPersisters();
        if ( persiters != null ) {
            for ( CollectionPersister collectionPersister : persiters.values() ) {
                if ( !collectionPersister.hasCache() ) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ( !(collectionPersister instanceof Joinable) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                String oneToManyFieldName = collectionPersister.getNodeName();
                EntityPersister ownerEntityPersister = collectionPersister.getOwnerEntityPersister();
                Class ownerClass = ownerEntityPersister.getMappedClass();

                // Logic to get the mappedBy attribute of the OneToMany annotation.
                BeanInformationFromClass bi = new BeanInformationFromClass( ownerClass );
                PropertyInformationFromClass prop = bi.getProperty( oneToManyFieldName );
                OneToMany oneToMany = prop.getAnnotation( OneToMany.class );
                String mappedBy = null;
                if ( oneToMany != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank( oneToMany.mappedBy() ) ) {
                    mappedBy = oneToMany.mappedBy();
                }
                mappedByFieldMapping.put( ((Joinable) collectionPersister).getName(), mappedBy );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        evictCache( event.getEntity(), event.getPersister(), event.getSession(), null );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDelete(PreDeleteEvent event) {
        evictCache( event.getEntity(), event.getPersister(), event.getSession(), null );
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        evictCache( event.getEntity(), event.getPersister(), event.getSession(), event.getOldState() );
        return false;
    }

    private void evictCache(Object entity, EntityPersister persister, EventSource session, Object[] oldState) {
        try {
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = persister.getFactory();

            Set<String> collectionRoles = factory.getCollectionRolesByEntityParticipant( persister.getEntityName() );
            if ( collectionRoles == null || collectionRoles.isEmpty() ) {
                return;
            }
            for ( String role : collectionRoles ) {
                CollectionPersister collectionPersister = factory.getCollectionPersister( role );
                if ( !collectionPersister.hasCache() ) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ( !(collectionPersister instanceof Joinable) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                String mappedBy = mappedByFieldMapping.get( ((Joinable) collectionPersister).getName() );
                if ( mappedBy != null ) {
                    int i = persister.getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyIndex( mappedBy );
                    Serializable oldId = null;
                    if ( oldState != null ) {
                        oldId = session.getIdentifier( oldState[i] );
                    }
                    Object ref = persister.getPropertyValue( entity, i );
                    Serializable id = null;
                    if ( ref != null ) {
                        id = session.getIdentifier( ref );
                    }
                    if ( id != null && !id.equals( oldId ) ) {
                        evict( id, collectionPersister, session );
                        if ( oldId != null ) {
                            evict( id, collectionPersister, session );
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    LOGGER.debug( "Evict CollectionRegion " + role );
                    collectionPersister.getCacheAccessStrategy().evictAll();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error( "", e );
        }
    }

    private void evict(Serializable id, CollectionPersister collectionPersister, EventSource session) {
        LOGGER.debug( "Evict CollectionRegion " + collectionPersister.getRole() + " for id " + id );
        collectionPersister.getCacheAccessStrategy().evict(
                session.generateCacheKey(
                        id,
                        collectionPersister.getKeyType(),
                        collectionPersister.getRole()
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a cache. A cache just should reduce database access. When you evict an object, then often you didn't do any modifications with the child objects, and they just can be loaded from the cache the next time. Also it often happens child objects are still used by other parent objects (in this case the name 'child' is not correct, because it is an n:1 or m:n relation). Evicting the children could provoke very strange errors somewhere else where the child objects are still in use.

So if it is good to evict the children just depends of your application and database design. Thus hibernate does not evict child objects by default.

If you want to have child objects evicted automatically, then use cascade="evict" in your mapping file.

A more rabiate method to evict all objects is to close the session and open a new one. Then all objects of the session are evicted.

Comment: I disagree with your points. Evicting children from cache would have no effect. If no references to child objects exist, this isn't a problem - it can be loaded on demand when necessary. Or if another class keeps a reference to cached collection, then again it's not a problem as hard reference still exists. But thanks for the hint on cascade="evict", I will have a look at this.